# Activate sandbox solution programmatically sharepoint 2013

Tags: sandbox-solution

I'm trying to activate a sandbox solution on SharePoint 2013 using C#.

This is the code that I am using, it's working and the solution is activated however the files in the solution are not copied to the Style Library.

SPSite tempSite = new SPSite(Global.url);

```
            SPUserToken ownertoken = tempSite.Owner.UserToken;

            using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(Global.url, ownertoken))
            {
                SPDocumentLibrary solutionGallery = (SPDocumentLibrary)siteCollection.GetCatalog(SPListTemplateType.SolutionCatalog);

                SPFile file = solutionGallery.RootFolder.Files.Add(Global.sharepointSolutionName, File.ReadAllBytes(Global.currentDirectory));

                SPUserSolution solution = siteCollection.Solutions.Add(file.Item.ID);


            }
```

If I upload and activate the same solution manually everything works great.

Any idea of what I am missing here to get the files in the directories?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to activate the feature that provisions the files.

```
siteCollection.Features.Add([guid_of_your)feature])
```